# Tag merge / synonym request: [compilers] → [compiler]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [compilers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilers) (212 questions) into [compiler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiler) (82), and make them synonyms.

Preference for master tag is because Wikipedia article uses singular form: [Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

---

Tag wikis appear to be almost identical (and both look like unattributed copies from Wikipedia article referred above, not good).

Comment: Note that this takes mod action because there are 1.25x compilers questions than compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have performed the merge and synonym.